# Twitch-Commando Error: Cannot Read Property 'Get' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, twitch, commando

Yo I'm trying to get TwitchBot's Twitch integration working via `twitch-commando` but keep getting this error:

```json
info: Register command system:eval
info: Register command system:help
info: Register command system:join
info: Register command system:part
info: Register command system:prefix
info: Register command admin:broadcast
info: Register command admin:create-channel
info: Register command mod:announce
info: Register command util:channel
info: Register command util:say
info: Register command util:user-info
info: Loading global emotes
info: Current default prefix is !
info: Connecting to Twitch Chat
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at TwitchCommandoClient.connect (/home/mountaint-dev/TwitchBot/node_modules/twitch-commando/src/client/TwitchCommandoClient.js:133:60)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

So basically I'm trying to figure out how to get it to show me what the `undefined` part is. I've been going back and forth trying multiple different logging methods but nothing seems to have helped at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my `index.js` code:

```js
const { TwitchCommandoClient, TwitchChatUser, TwitchChatMessage, CommandoSQLiteProvider } = require('twitch-commando');
const eslint = require('eslint');
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const TOKEN = process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN;
const env1 = process.env.OWNER_1;
const env2 = process.env.OWNER_2;

var client = new TwitchCommandoClient({
    username: 'TwitchBot',
    commandPrefix: '!',
    oauth: '',
    channels: '',
    botOwners: [env1, env2],
    disableEveryone: true,
    unknownCommandResponse: false
});

client.enableVerboseLogging();

client.setProvider(sqlite.open(path.join(__dirname, 'database')).then(db => new CommandoSQLiteProvider(db))
);

client.registerDetaultCommands();
client.registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, 'commands'));

client.on("ready", function () {
    console.log(`the client becomes ready to start`);
    console.log(`I am ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.cache.size} users, in ${client.channels.cache.size} channels of ${client.guilds.cache.size} guilds.`);

    client.user.setActivity("the upright organ");
    client.generateInvite(['SEND_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_GUILD', 'MENTION_EVERYONE'])
        .then(link => {
            console.log(`Generated bot invite link: ${link}`);
            inviteLink = link;
        });
});

client.on("reconnecting", function () {
    console.log(`client tries to reconnect to the WebSocket`);
});

client.on("resume", function (replayed) {
    console.log(`whenever a WebSocket resumes, ${replayed} replays`);
});

client.on("warn", function (info) {
    console.log(`warn: ${info}`);
});

client.on("debug", function (info) {
    console.log(`debug -> ${info}`);
});

client.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(`client's WebSocket encountered a connection error: ${error}`);
});

client.on("message", function (message) {
    console.log(`message is created -> ${message}`);
});


client.connect(TOKEN).catch(console.error);
```

And here is my `package.json` with all of our Dependencies listed:

```json
{
    "name": "twitchbot",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "description": "Twitch Integration bot built using Discord.js Commando and Twitch API",
    "author": "Discord Coding Community <https://github.com/Discord-Coding-Community>",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/Discord-Coding-Community/TwitchBot"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "twitch",
        "bot",
        "chatbot",
        "chat",
        "commando"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "dev": "nodemon index.js"
    },
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "better-queue": "^3.8.10",
        "common-tags": "^1.8.0",
        "discord.js": "^12.5.1",
        "discord.js-commando": "^0.11.1",
        "enmap": "5.8.4",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "eslint": "^7.18.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "loader": "^2.1.1",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
        "recursive-readdir-sync": "^1.0.6",
        "recursive-readdir-synchronous": "0.0.4",
        "sleep": "^6.1.0",
        "sqlite": "^4.0.19",
        "tmi.js": "^1.5.0",
        "twitch-commando": "^1.0.12",
        "winston": "^3.2.1",
        "discord-error-handler": "^1.1.6",
        "discord.js-light": "^3.5.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "clean-documentation-theme": "^0.5.2",
        "jsdoc": "^3.6.3",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "^12.0.0"
    }
}
```

This is the `.eslintrc.json` file I am using:

```json
{
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2019
    },
    "rules": {
        "brace-style": [
            "error",
            "stroustrup",
            {
                "allowSingleLine": true
            }
        ],
        "comma-dangle": [
            "error",
            "always-multiline"
        ],
        "comma-spacing": "error",
        "comma-style": "error",
        "curly": [
            "error",
            "multi-line",
            "consistent"
        ],
        "dot-location": [
            "error",
            "property"
        ],
        "handle-callback-err": "off",
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "max-nested-callbacks": [
            "error",
            {
                "max": 4
            }
        ],
        "max-statements-per-line": [
            "error",
            {
                "max": 2
            }
        ],
        "no-console": "off",
        "no-empty-function": "error",
        "no-floating-decimal": "error",
        "no-inline-comments": "error",
        "no-lonely-if": "error",
        "no-multi-spaces": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
            "error",
            {
                "max": 2,
                "maxEOF": 1,
                "maxBOF": 0
            }
        ],
        "no-shadow": [
            "error",
            {
                "allow": [
                    "err",
                    "resolve",
                    "reject"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "no-trailing-spaces": [
            "error"
        ],
        "no-var": "error",
        "object-curly-spacing": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "prefer-const": "error",
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "space-before-blocks": "error",
        "space-before-function-paren": [
            "error",
            {
                "anonymous": "never",
                "named": "never",
                "asyncArrow": "always"
            }
        ],
        "space-in-parens": "error",
        "space-infix-ops": "error",
        "space-unary-ops": "error",
        "spaced-comment": "error",
        "yoda": "error"
    }
}
```

Would be more than grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

**Note:**
As pointed out below there is a typo in `client.registerDetaultCommands();`. However, it seems that typo is unfortunately on the `twitch-commando` side as changing it to `client.registerDefaultCommands();` breaks the flag.

Comment: Hi Joshua, please provide us with more information. it appears that something is undefined, and hence the error message. a good step would be console.log'ing your env variables to make sure they are all there. Edit: also there is a typo in your code `client.registerDetaultCommands();` should be `client.registerDefaultCommands()`

Comment: ty. I'll fix the typo rn. unfortunately  have no idea what to add for the logging. but will see if i can figure something out for the logs. I'm suspecting twitch-commando might not be running discord.js 12 tbh but I have no idea how to check since it's an NPM package xD

Comment: ok so that flag is typoed in the command itself. with the t it works but with proper spelling it doesn't. Will have to let the creator of twitch-commando know about that one it seems since it pulls th default commands from the npm package

Comment: The page for the `Twitch-Commando` npm package can be found here if it helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitch-commando

Comment: Updated a bit. I've tried adding a `.catch(console.error)` to it but it keeps rejecting it saying `.catch` is not a function. So I added `nodemon` to see if it would at least tell a bit more... unfortunately it's telling me to add a `.catch` block which didn't work at all for me when I tried.

Comment: Yo how do I log the errors for this? I've been trying to figure out what error logging method i need to use to make it send the error like you said to but I can't figure it out.